# Удаление контекстного меню окна WPF

Tags: c#, wpf

Мне необходимо сделать с помощью WPF окошко, у которого нет заголовка. Казалось бы все просто `WindowStyle=None`, но есть один большой подводный камень, а именно, контекстное меню с функциями закрытия, перемещения, сворачивания/разворачивания окна. Я пробовал в свойствах окна задать `ContextMenu="{x:Null}"`, но меню по прежнему отображается по клику правой кнопкой мыши. Можно ли его отключить?

Comment: У вас что то установлено дополнительно, например `WindowChrome`. Если воспроизвести на чистом WPF проекте окно с `WindowStyle=None`, то там меню не будет.

Comment: А возможно, Вы правы. Спасибо. Буду копать.